# MongoDB mongoose ExpressJs Angular

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, коллекции, mongoose

Нужна ваша помощь с максимально простым вопросом:

Вопрос: Как "расширить" модель mongoose ?

Вводные: Например есть ExpressJs + mongoose:
При регистрации пользователя данные email+pass

```
{
  id: string(autogenerated),
  email: string(autogenerated),
  password: string(autogenerated)
}
```

Уже в ЛК он заполняет полные данные например добавляются поля:

```
{
  title: string,
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  gender: string,
  dateOfBirth: string,
  registerDate: string,
  phone: string,
  picture: string,
  location: string
}
```

Потом в Angular например есть сервис который просто получается данные условно

getUserPreview() - Возвращает ФИО

getUserFull() - Возвращает Полные данные

Как можно такое сделать?

Очень прошу вас подсказать визуально, читать я хорошо умею но воспринимаю зрительно к сожалению, знаю что есть ссылка **ref: 'что-то'**  на другую коллекцию, но не понимаю как это работает.

Comment: вам нужно добавить полей в эту коллекцию и не нужно создавать другие. а вещи типа `getUserPreview` делаются просто перечислением в запросе кастомного списка возвращаемых полей

Comment: Биг Мерси, помогло.